# ¿Cómo obtener el nombre de usuario con Google OAuth en python?

Tags: python, oauth2, oauth, google-oauth

Estoy tratando de *loguear* a mis usuarios con el servicio de autenticación de google. Quiero guardar en mi base de datos el nombre y email de dichos usuarios y, por lo tanto, lo tengo que obtener mientras se está logueando. Pero no puedo:

```
google = oauth.remote_app(
    'google',
    consumer_key='unacontraseña',
    consumer_secret='otracontraseña'
    request_token_params={
        'scope': 'email'
    },
    base_url='https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/',
    request_token_url=None,
    access_token_method='POST',
    access_token_url='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
    authorize_url='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
)

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
      return render_template('login.html')
```

Donde `login.html` tiene un botón que si es apretado me redirige a la siguiente función:

```
 @app.route('/login/authorized_google')
 def authorized_google():
    resp = google.authorized_response()
    if resp is None:
        return 'Access denied'
    else:
        session['google_token'] = (resp['access_token'], '')
        me = google.get('user')
    try:
        user = User.select().where(User.social_id == str(me.data['login'])).get()
    except:
        user = User.create(email = str(me.data['email']), 
                           nickname = str(me.data['name']),
                           social_id  = str(me.data['login']))
    global current_user
    current_user = user
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

El error que devuelve es: `index is str and may be int`.
Eso me dice que por ejemplo:

```
   me.data['email']
```

Está mal, pero entonces no se cómo obtener el email y el resto de los campos de `me`.

Comment: Hola @Igna94. Por lo que veo, estás usando algún *"framework web"*, posiblemente flask. Puesto que no parece que esté ahí el problema, ¿podrías reconstruir la pregunta quitando las partes de la aplicación web que no son esenciales? Añade también la salida del atributo `me.data`, quita los `try..except` para saber exáctamente dónde está el error, y adjunta el texto del error completo. Tiene pinta de que lo que obtienes en `me.data` es una cadena de caracteres, no un diccionario.

Comment: gracias @ChemaCortes si, estaba usando flask, si: hice eso,y como dices el error estaba en 'me', específicamente en  el get, ya que debía ser me = google.get('userinfo')  saludos !

Comment: Entiendo entonces que ya te funciona. ¿Podrías añadir la solución como respuesta a tu pregunta?

Answer (score 2):

Encontré la solución,
el error está en la linea:

```
me = google.get('user')
```

lo correcto es:

```
me = google.get('infouser')
```